# For two injective mappings $f$ and $g$ which one is correct?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two non empty sets and let

$f: X \to Y$ AND $g: Y \to X$ be two mappings . IF both $f$ and $g$ are injective 
 then

(a) $X$ and $Y$ must be infinite sets

(b) $g =f^{-1}$

(c) One of $fog: Y \to X $ and $gof: X \to Y$ is always bijective

(d) There exists a bijective map $h: X \to Y$

Since $f$ and $g$ are injective hence ,  $\left|X\right| \le \left|Y\right|$ and

$\left|Y\right| \le \left|X\right|$ Thus $\left|X\right| = \left|Y\right|$

Since both f, g are injective  $fog, gof$ are also injective also $\left|X\right| = \left|Y\right|$, Thus both

mappings are bijective.

Hence (c) must be correct choice.

Is My answer correct ?

Comment: Not quite. Up to “$f\circ g$, $g\circ f$ are also injective also $|X|=|Y|$” you are correct. However, your asserting that “mappings are bijective” is incorrect. For example, take $X=Y=\mathbb{Z}$, and let both $f$ and $g$ be multiplication by $2$. Then both are injective, but neither of $f\circ g$ nor $g\circ f$ are bijective. Nor is $g=f^{-1}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Yes, you are right I forgot to consider the case of infinite sets,For two Finite sets an injective map is bijective, while it may be false for infinite sets.

Comment: So, I think option (d) must be correct. Since $|X|$ = $|Y|$ we can find a bijective map between two sets .   Is my reasoning correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) is not correct. Take the example of bijective maps between finite sets.

(b) is not correct. Take $X=Y= \mathbb N$, $f(n)=2n$ and $g(n)=3n$.

(c) is not correct. Take the examples of (b) as a counterexample.

(d) is correct. This is the theorem of [Cantor-Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem?wprov=sfti1).